# Nodejs - Getting mongoose typescript error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

## Typescript error

**I am using the same schema approach in all over my backend but only this one gives an error for some reason**. It was running fine until this morning.

All the other schemas in the website have exactly the same approach but this one is throwing an error.

> **Error :**

```
[ERROR] 19:52:58 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/models/project.ts(81,3): error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.
src/models/project.ts(83,17): error TS7006: Parameter 'doc' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/models/project.ts(83,22): error TS7006: Parameter 'ret' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/models/project.ts(90,15): error TS2551: Property 'statics' does not exist on type 'Schema'. 
Did you mean 'static'?
```

> **Schema :**

```js
interface ProjectAttrs {
  user: string;
  profile: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  type: categories;
}

export interface ProjectDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  user: string;
  profile: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  collabImages: string[];
  description: string;
  comments: string[];
  likes: number;
  likers: ProfileDoc[];
  state: boolean;
  // requesters: ProfileDoc[];
  requests: string[];
  team: string[];
  type: categories;
}

interface ProjectModel extends mongoose.Model<ProjectDoc> {
  build(attrs: ProjectAttrs): ProjectDoc;
}

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    profile: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Profile",
    },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String },
    collabImages: [{ type: String,
        required: false}],
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}],
    state: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    likers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Profile"}],
    requests: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Request"}],
    team: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Profile"}],
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(doc, ret) { // ERROR 
        ret.id = ret._id;   // ERROR 
        delete ret._id;     // ERROR
      },
    },
  }
);
projectSchema.statics.build = (attrs: ProjectAttrs) => {
  return new Project(attrs);
};
const Project = mongoose.model<ProjectDoc, ProjectModel>(
  "Project",
  projectSchema
);
export { Project };
```

I wonder what is it that I am missing here. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm having the same error. Let me know if you find a solution please!

Comment: Its weird, I got rid of this error after I removed one of the route I recently created. Its not an issue with the schema.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to remove `@types/mongoose` and update `mongoose` to its **latest version**. It seems like *latest mongoose* version already ships with its types included and it's causing a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

according to mongoose documentation some changes are needed.

please look following code

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface ProjectAttrs {
  user: string;
  profile: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  type: categories;
}

export interface ProjectDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  user: string;
  profile: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  collabImages: string[];
  description: string;
  comments: string[];
  likes: number;
  likers: ProfileDoc[];
  state: boolean;
  // requesters: ProfileDoc[];
  requests: string[];
  team: string[];
  type: categories;
}

interface ProjectModel extends mongoose.Model<ProjectDoc> {
  build(attrs: ProjectAttrs): ProjectDoc;
}

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    profile: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Profile",
    },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String },
    collabImages: [{ type: String,
        required: false}],
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}],
    state: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    likers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Profile"}],
    requests: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Request"}],
    team: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Profile"}],
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  }
);



//REVIEW THIS PART SINCE SOMETHING MIGHT BE MISSING
schema.set('toJson', {transform:function(doc: any, ret:any) {
  ret.id = ret._id;
  delete ret._id;
}});


//THIS WAS CHANGED NO LONGER STATICS
projectSchema.static('build', (attrs: ProjectAttrs) => {
  return new Project(attrs);
});


const Project = mongoose.model<ProjectDoc, ProjectModel>(
  "Project",
  projectSchema
);
export { Project };
```